# Phonegap BlackBerry popup on ajax response with 403 statuscode

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, cordova, blackberry

I'm building a application using PhoneGap an jQuery that communicates with an authenticated API. The API will respond with statuscode 403 when the user did not sign in succesfully. On Android and iOS this can be handled using JavaScript. However, on BlackBerry I always get an "authentication popup". Is there any way to disable this popup?

Thanks in advance!